# ios - iphone notes application

Tags: ios

I am studying how to make iPhone apps - and I learn best by dissecting the source code and see why something works the way it does.

I was wondering if anyone new if there is a clone app of the apple's notes app that I could check the source code on. Not to publish in the store myself, but to learn how certain things are done.

I am getting a pretty good Idea, I just want to compare what I have learned so far to an actual note app:-)

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one in case anyone else wants to go through this exercise as well.

https://github.com/vkoser/PlainNote

Jeff